# Oozie Spark2 Action throws "Attempt to add ({dependencyJar}) multiple times to the distributed cache."

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

Getting the below error while trying to load the dependency jar for oozie spark2 action. Added workflow.xml below.

***Error:***

> 2019-06-12 07:00:35,140  WARN SparkActionExecutor:523 -
>   SERVER[manager-0] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[spark-wf]
>   JOB[0000068-190611183932696-oozie-root-W]
>   ACTION[0000068-190611183932696-oozie-root-W@spark-node] Launcher
>   ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain],
>   main() threw exception, 
>   **Attempt to add (hdfs://${nameNode}/${workflowAppUri}/lib/${dependencyJar}) 
>   multiple times to the distributed cache.**

***workflow.xml***

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="spark-wf">
    <start to="spark-node"/>
    <action name="spark-node">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <name>test_spark</name>
            <class>${className}</class>
            <jar>${workflowAppUri}/lib/${executableJar}</jar>
            <spark-opts>--jars ${workflowAppUri}/lib/${dependencyJar}</spark-opts>
            <arg>${arg1}</arg>
            <arg>${arg2}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

This is not the same issue related to duplicate jars in oozie and spark2 sharelib directory. Have removed the duplicate jars in spark2 sharelib. But that doesn't help.

What could be the reason for this? 
Please help me with this!!!

Comment: Which version of Oozie do you use? Does it include https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2802?

Comment: @attila_sThanks for the reply,  I am using HDP 2.6.5 cluster. The default version of oozie is 4.2.0. I have given my analysis in the answer action

Answer (score 0):

If we add jars in the lib directory of the application root directory, oozie automatically distributing the jars to it's distributed cache. In my case, I have tried to add the jar which is already in the lib directory. So, I just need to remove the below line from my workflow definition.

```
<spark-opts>--jars ${workflowAppUri}/lib/${dependencyJar}</spark-opts>
```

And also I have tested that if you want to attach the jars that are not available in your lib directory, you can mention like below in your workflow definition.

```
<spark-opts>--jars ${nameNode}/tmp/{someJar}</spark-opts>
```